# MouseMoveEvent in QGraphicsView

Tags: c++, qt, events, qgraphicsview

I need to get a move event in my main widget but the QGraphicsView catches the event, so I can't get it in my main widget. is there any way to turn this off, so i can catch the event like i would catch any mousemoveevent in my widget. Note: The problem is NOT that i have mousetracking disabled. I know about that and catching this event outside the graphicsview is working

Comment: To with installing an event filter on the QGraphicsView and intercept the move event.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two possible solutions among dozens of them:

### Ignore

From documentation:

> You should call ignore() if the mouse event is not handled by your
>   widget. A mouse event is propagated up the parent widget chain until a
>   widget accepts it with accept(), or an event filter consumes it.

```
// view.cpp

mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event){
event.ignore(); // propagated to parent
}
```

### Double event

Try emitting a signal with mouse position from QGraphicsView, when a move event occurs, and catch it in main widget.

```
// view.cpp

mouseMoveEvent (QMouseEvent *event){
    emit mouseMoveSignal(event.pos());
    }


// mainwindow.cpp

mainWindow::mainWindow (QWidget * parent = 0){
    connect(view, SIGNAL(mouseMoveSignal(QPointF)), this, SLOT(mouseMoveSlot(QPointF)));
}
```

Comment: Event filters seem to be more convenient solution. Passing mouse events data through signal-slot system could be too slow and cannot be recommended. I don't understand why you wrote "double event" because signals are not events and should not be confused with them.

Comment: double event: IN CASE you need to catch the event in BOTH widgets. I know the question is NOT asking that; he wants to ignore the event. I just like to express as many approaches I can. Just being curious, is there easier, an obvious way of doing that? Of course, one can also apply an event filter to child, and invoke mouseMoveEvent of the parent widget (I think dynamic casts needed here), when move event of child occurs. I thought signals are easier to handle.